# Domain of an integral function

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> Find the domain of $F(x)$, defined by$$F(x)=-\int_0^{x}{\log(\cos t)}dt$$

**My attempt:**

$$f(x)=\log(\cos x), \ D(f(x))=\left(-\frac\pi{2},\frac\pi{2}\right)$$

So I did this:

$$-\int_{0}^{-\frac\pi{2}}{\log(\cos t)}dt =\int_{-\frac\pi{2}}^{0}{\log(\cos t)}dt$$

I am having problems with determining whether this integral converges or not.

I tried using Taylor: $\int_{-\frac\pi{2}}^{0}{\log(t+\frac{\pi}2)}dt$, but I don't know how to go on.

I then tried substituting $x=t+\frac{\pi}2$ so: $\int_{0}^{\frac\pi{2}}{\log(\cos x)}dx$ but I don't know how to go on either.

**EDIT: New attempt:**

I continued from here: $$\int_{-\frac\pi{2}}^{0}{\log\left(t+\frac{\pi}2\right)}dt = \int_{-\frac\pi{2}}^{0}{\dfrac{1}{\log^{-1}(t+\frac{\pi}2)}}dt$$ then I substituted: ($y=t+\frac{\pi}2$)

$$\int_{-\frac\pi{2}}^{0}{\dfrac{1}{\log^{-1}(t+\frac{\pi}2)}}dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}{\dfrac{1}{\log^{-1}(y)}}dy$$ 
which converges (it should converge negatively but I got positively) because $\log^{-1}(y)<\sqrt{y}$ (for example).

The same can be said for $\int_{0}^{\frac\pi{2}}{\log(\cos t)}dt$ so $D_{F(x)}=\left[-\dfrac\pi{2},\dfrac\pi{2}\right]$, am I right?

I have got another problem though: I checked on *[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vy9pafqsws)* and the integral converges negatively where I thought positively.

Comment: but $$\cos(t)$$ must be greater than zero

Comment: I believe that $F(x)$ is defined only where $\cos(t)>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this function to be well-defined, we need, at first that $\log(\cos(t))$ is well defined. So, we need that:
$$\cos(t)>0\Rightarrow t\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
or every other interval $\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, $x$ can be, also, any number in $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, since $0\leq t\leq x$.

To conclude, $$D_F=\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

**Edit:** We could extend $F$ to $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ by setting:
$$F(x)=-\int_{A_x}\log(\cos t)dt$$
where
$$A_x=(0,x)\cap\left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$
if $x>0$ and 
$$A_x=(x,0)\cap\left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$
if $x<0$.

Comment: I don't think this can be correct since if we choose $x = 2\pi+\pi/2$, we are going to have to integrate over $[0,2\pi+\pi/2)$, and the function $\log(\cos t)$ is not defined over the entire interval. Should just be the first interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Don't I have to check if the integrals at the limit of the domain of the integrand converge? (in this case: $-\frac{\pi}2$ and $\frac{\pi}2$)

Comment: It is easy to check that $\log(\cos(x))$ is strictly decreasing over $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, so, for every $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ - for $x\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},0)$ we can work in the same way: $$\int_0^x\log(\cos x)dt\leq\int_0^x\log(\cos t)dt\leq\int_0^x\log(\cos0)dt$$ which means that $$x\log(\cos x)\leq-F(x)\leq0\Rightarrow0\leq F(x)\leq x\log(\cos x)$$, so $F(x)$ is a (finite) number for every $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

@AOrtiz.Well, $\cup(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})$ does not include every $[2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2},2(k+1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so it's all right.

Comment: I second the comment from @AOrtiz. The integral is well defined as a Riemann integral only if $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. If $x\notin(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ then the interval of integration includes at least one of the troublesome points where the integrand is not defined.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point, I just have it in my mind - yet not expressed it right, so it's my writting that created problems - as a more generalised $F(x)$, as defined by:
$$F(x)=-\int_{A_x}\log(\cos t)dt$$
where $A_x=(0,x)\cap(\cup(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi+\frac{\pi){2})$
So, I will edit the answer, to clarify this.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that $\int_{0}^{\frac\pi{2}}{\log(\cos(t))}dt$ converges, so shouldn't the domain be $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$?

Comment: Should $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then couldn't $\cos t=0$. I mean, I think that you can extend $F$ over $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, since the integral converges, but it's natural domain should be $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.